# "Oops! Something Bad Happened" on Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

It appears people's CV are not working.

[Example working profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters)

[Example broken CV](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/zopatista)

Comment: Holy frick, something bad happened indeed. That's not Martijn Pieters. That's a photo of some guy ...

Comment: I can repro this and I am looking into it.

Comment: @StevenPenny can you try this again please?

Comment: @NickLarsen for posterity can you explain what happened?

Comment: @StevenPenny truthfully I'm not exactly sure, there were a lot of infrastructure things changing on our network and we were experiencing intermittent failures on a lot of our internal services.  I just waited until all of that stuff calmed down and asked you to try it again.